# Select date query with time format is not working with JDBCTemplate and util.Date

Tags: java, spring, date, jdbctemplate

I am using Spring JDBCTemplate to conneect DB. When I am selecting date in DB using below query

`select to_date(valid_to,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from composition`

output is, 31-12-99 23:59:59.

But, when I am using the same with JDBCTemplate like below,

```
Date d = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select to_date(valid_to,'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS') from composition",Date.class);
```

outpt is 2099-12-31 00:00:00.0.

Time is not correct. I also need the same time in Date class. How to get that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your response. I found a way to take the time.

```
String dateString = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select to_char(valis_to, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from composition",String.class);
Date date = sdf.parse(dateString);
```

Comment: This code is fine since the column valid_to table index_composition doesn't seem to be a date according to the use of the to_date function in your original guery.
For a date column I would realy consider using the class java.sql.Timestamp

Comment: Using `java.sql.Timestamp` is way better than `to_char` conversion that relies on a specific RDBMS vendors implementation.

Answer (score 8):

You need to use `java.sql.Timestamp`. `java.sql.Date` does not have a time component, so its time is always 00:00:00.

Comment: Assuming that is `java.sql.Date` they are using not `java.util.Date`

Answer (score 5):

java.sql.Date don't retain the hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds since it mirrors the date type in SQL. Simply ask for a java.sql.Timestamp instead of a Date. Since Timestamp is a subtype of java.util.Date, you can ask it directly.

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

[...]

Date d = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select to_date(valid_to,'DD-MM-YY HH24:MI:SS') from index_composition", Timestamp.class);
```

Comment: Can you provide some explanation to your answer?

Answer (score 1):

You must be importing `java.sql.Date`. Instead use `java.util.Date` or `java.util.Timestamp`.

`java.sql.Date` will truncate time.

Comment: As far I know `queryForObject` doesn't work with `java.util.Date`

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 allows us to use a better suited Date classes (in java.time.*). 
The convertion from LocalDate (java) to sql date is done by: `java.sql.Date.valueOf(LocalDate.of(2012, Month.DECEMBER, 12))`

Oracle advise to use java 8 Dates instead of the oldest version :

> These classes had several drawbacks, including:

```
The Calendar class was not type safe.
Because the classes were mutable, they could not be used in multithreaded applications.
Bugs in application code were common due to the unusual numbering of months and the lack of type safety.
```