# retrieving timestamp value from database using Spring JDBC Template

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am working on a `java Spring` project. I am implementing a password recovery function. There I need to compare two `timestamp` values which are current time and the token expiration time. To retrieve the expiration timestamp value from the database I am using this code.

```
String sql = "SELECT expiray_time FROM recover_password WHERE token = "+token;
java.sql.Timestamp ex_time = getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(sql, java.sql.Timestamp);
```

But the `java.sql.Timestamp` type is not recognized. Is this way of retrieving wrong?
Any other way of retrieving timestamp data from database using `JdbcTemplate`

Thank you!

Comment: Above method used for static SQL. you need to use other method  
queryForObject(String sql, Object[] args, Class requiredType). As per spring documentation.

Comment: The import java.sql.Timestamp; is included in your project?

Comment: Also check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17249574/select-date-query-with-time-format-is-not-working-with-jdbctemplate-and-util-dat

Comment: @PatrickLC I didn't get you. I have imported it. What do you meant by include?

Comment: My question is if you could succesfully run this piece of code: import java.util.Date;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date testtime = new Date();
        Timestamp t = new Timestamp (testtime.getTime());
        System.out.println ("TIMESTAMP=" + t + " getTime:" + t.getTime());
    }
}

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieving Timestamp value from mysql database using Spring JDBC template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27330856/retrieving-timestamp-value-from-mysql-database-using-spring-jdbc-template)

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify it as a class param:

```
String sql = "SELECT expiray_time FROM recover_password WHERE token = "+token;
java.sql.Timestamp ex_time = getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(sql, java.sql.Timestamp.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
String sql = "SELECT expiray_time FROM recover_password WHERE token = ?";

Object[] args = new Object[] {//token object};
Object obj = getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(sql, args, java.sql.Timestamp);
```

or try this:

```
String sql = "SELECT expiray_time FROM recover_password WHERE token = "+token;
java.sql.Timestamp ex_time = getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(sql, new Object[] { token } , java.sql.Timestamp);
```