# Retrieving Timestamp value from mysql database using Spring JDBC template

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am implementing a password recovery function in a Java project based on Spring. This is my methodology for that

1. User clicks forgot password link
2. In the next screen, user enter his email address which has been used to register his/her account
3. System generates a `UUID`token and it is saved in a database table together with the email address user entered. In addition the expiry time is saved in database as a `Timestamp` value
4. An email including a link to reset password is sent to user. (UUID token is included in the e mail)
5. When user clicks the link in the email, he/she is redirected to password reset page.
6. In that page, user's email address is automatically set in to the text field by the system using the `UUID` token.
   Here I need to check whether the expiry time is due. For that I need to compare the `Timestamp value` of current time with the `Timestamp value` of the expiry time which is taken from the database using `UUID token.`

I used this code segment to retrieve the `timestamp` value of the expiry time.

```
    @Override
        public String checkValidityOfToken(UUID token) {

            System.out.println("INFO:token in Login Dao Impl = "+token);
            java.sql.Timestamp  ex_time;
            try{
                String sql = "SELECT expiray_time FROM recover_password WHERE token = "+token;
                ex_time = getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(sql, java.sql.Timestamp);
                System.out.println("INFO: first total = "+ex_time);
            }catch(Exception exx){
                System.out.println("error while taking saved time count for a matching token "+exx);
            }
}
```

Although the `java.sql.Timestamp` at `queryForObject()` is suggested by Eclipse when I hit `ctrl+space`, Eclipse shows an error there. Why is that.
What is the correct code segment for this task.

Then I used this,

```
String sql = "SELECT expiray_time FROM recover_password WHERE token = ?";
ex_time = getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject( sql, new Object[] { token }, java.sql.Timestamp);
```

In this case also, the `java.sql.Timestamp` is not recognized. The class which includes above method extends `SimpleJdbcDaoSupport.

**OR**

Do I use a wrong way of checking the validity of the password reset link? If so What is a good way to implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`queryForObject(String, Class)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-) method takes [`Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) instance as its second parameter. Therefore the correct syntax is this:

```
getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(sql, java.sql.Timestamp.class);
```

The code you are using is not valid Java code, which is the reason why it doesn't compile.